# set Aptana Studio to not use ^M characters

Tags: aptana3

I've been trying to find any setting in Aptana Studio 3 which will allow me to not use ^M characters for newlines, as I work on linux and this makes the code very ugly when I open with VIM.

I've looked through the settings many times, and done some google searches, oddly I haven't found anything applicable. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making Aptana Studio 3 using different line endings, you could try executing
`:set ff=dos` in vim to use the same line endings.

Comment: thanks for the post, but when working with lots of different people on different systems I don't want to have to force people to deal with my ^M's in every file. Ended up switching IDEs just because of something silly (but crucial) like that :(